# "System.InvalidOperationException" в System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Пытаюсь заинсертить 2 сущности, данные которых получены из WinForms. Но выскакивает "Вызвано исключение: "System.InvalidOperationException" в System.Data.dll". Я так понимаю, исключение возникает по попытке сделать команду SQL. У меня в коде где-то ошибка? И можно ли как-то развернуть исключение, чтобы понять, где проблема? Потому что при отладке в стек трейсе у меня пусто, а в консоле лишь оповещение об исключении...
Сам код запроса:

```
public void Add(Human human, Address address)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Addresses values (@address)";
            command.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = address.AddressName;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int id = FindLastId(connection);
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Humen values (@name, @surname, @middlename, @birthday, @phoneNumber, @addressId, @houseNumber, @flat)";
            command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = human.Name;
            command.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = human.Surname;
            command.Parameters.Add("@middlename", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = human.MiddleName;
            command.Parameters.Add("@birthday", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = human.Birthday;
            command.Parameters.Add("@phoneNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = human.Number;
            command.Parameters.Add("@addressId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            command.Parameters.Add("@houseNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = human.HouseNumber;
            command.Parameters.Add("@flat", SqlDbType.Int).Value = human.Flat;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    private int FindLastId(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", connection);
        return Convert.ToInt32(command1.ExecuteScalar());
    }
```

База данных.

[image: База Данных]

Comment: Здравствуйте. Отредактируйте вопрос, указав в какой именно строке возникает исключение. Ошибка возникает при подключении к базе данных? При создании экземпляра какого-то класса? При выполнении запроса?

Comment: @Frehzy, вот я и сам не могу понять, так как стек трейс пуст., и пометок никаких нигде не вижу, или оповещений.

Comment: Но у вас ведь появляется ошибка. В какой она строке появляется? Добавьте хоть скриншот что-ли прям из visualstudio, где видна ошибка. Она ведь появляется напротив строки, в которой произошёл код. Вы ведь как-то поняли, что исключение есть. Как вы это поняли? Вот это и покажите

Comment: @Frehzy в том то и дело, я просмотрел абсолютно все классы - никаких пометок... Вот сделал скрин студии https://ibb.co/Lz9021j. Исключение написано только в выводе, подробно посмотреть не знаю как... В стеке вызовов пусто, никаких оповещений и пр.

Comment: Не задана строка соединения в `SqlConnection`

Comment: `string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=usersdb;Integrated Security=True"; using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))` Не хватает connectionString (это только пример. У вас своя строка подключения должна быть)

Comment: @Frehzy да, спасибо. Моя невнимательность... Правда теперь вылезло Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll. Возможно, я бы и сам разобрался во всех этих исключениях, но я просто не понимаю, почему стек трейс пуст и никаких оповещений. Это где-то сторонне включается? Очень странно, в общем...

Comment: Оборачивайте код в `try-catch`, чтобы видеть исключение

Comment: `insert` и `select scope_identity()` нужно выполнять в одном запросе (скоупе). Иначе можно получить значения другого запроса, выполненного в другом потоке/процессе.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov спасибо. Хотелось бы конечно удобства, но это лучше, чем ничего!